# При запуске программы и выборе вводных данных программа закрывается

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('Material2')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Просчет заказа', size=(20, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 25), relief=sg.RELIEF_RAISED)],
    [sg.Text('Введите вводные данные и выберите, в чем они выражаются', justification='center')],
    [sg.InputText('', justification='center', size=(10, 1), key='1'),
     sg.InputCombo(('квадратные мм', 'кубические мм', 'упаковки'), key='2', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Text('Введите длину, ширину и высоту обьекта в мм', key='VIS1')],
    [sg.InputText('', visible=False, key='VIS2', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText('', visible=False, key='VIS3', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText('', visible=False, key='VIS4', size=(10, 1))],
    [sg.Text('Введите вес одного обьекта / одной штуки в упаковке в тоннах', justification='center', key='weighty')],
    [sg.InputText('', key='3')],
    [sg.Text('Сколько штук в упаковке?', justification='center', key='VIS5', visible=False)],
    [sg.InputText('', visible=False, key='VIS6')],
    [sg.Text('Введите цену доставки', justification='center')],
    [sg.InputText('', key='4')],
    [sg.Text('Введите процент накрутки', justification='center')],
    [sg.InputText('', key='5')],
    [sg.Text('Введите цену закупки', justification='center')],
    [sg.InputText('', key='PRIZ')],
    [sg.Submit('Получить цену'), sg.Cancel('Отмена')]]
window = sg.Window('Просчет Заказа', layout, default_element_size=(10, 1), grab_anywhere=False)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or 'Отмена':
        break

    upk = values['2']
    if upk == 'квадратные мм':
        window['VIS1'](visible=True)
        window['VIS2'](visible=True)
        window['VIS3'](visible=True)

    if upk == 'кубические мм':
        window['VIS1'](visible=True)
        window['VIS2'](visible=True)
        window['VIS3'](visible=True)
        window['VIS4'](visible=True)

    if upk == 'упаковки':
        window['VIS1'](visible=False)
        window['VIS2'](visible=False)
        window['VIS3'](visible=False)
        window['VIS4'](visible=False)
        window['VIS5'](visible=True)
        window['VIS6'](visible=True)

    if event == "Получить цену":
        X = values['VIS2']
        Y = values['VIS3']
        Z = values['VIS4']
        KG = values['3']
        KO = values['VIS6']
        PR = values['PRIZ']
        EX = values['4']
        PER = values['5']
        sg.Popup('Клиент должен заплатить', int('X') * int('Y') * int('Z') * int('KG') * int('KO') * int('PR') + int('EX') * float('PER'), 'рублей')
window.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто уберите `window.Close()` и все будет хорошо работать